# Sonos Search categories customization for Sonos mobile application (ios/android)

Tags: search, sonos

It seems that a have some confusion with the search categories for dekstop vs mobile Sonos clients.

Currently our mobile client displays some additional search categories: 'Artists', 'Genres', 'Stations', which are not mentioned around desktop client. And search doesn't work around that mobile client specific categories.

Please point me how can I format pmap.xml to make that work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that you're mapping search to existing, canonical search categories, where applicable.